# Getting Username from Slack API

Tags: node.js, slack-api, botkit

I'm building a slackbot that needs to listen for an ambient keyword but checks to make sure a particular user wrote the keyword. I'm trying to test the command right now with this:

```js
controller.hears(['texas'], 'ambient', function(bot, message) {
  username = users.info.name;
  bot.reply(message, username);
});
```

Eventually, I want to run conditional logic to make sure a username matches the user I want the bot to respond to. This isn't working though; am I using the API wrong? How do I retrieve the username, and how do I check to make sure it's the correct user?

Answer (score 5):

You would do something like this:

```
controller.hears(['texas'], 'ambient', function(bot, message) {
  bot.api.users.info({user: message.user}, function(err, info){
    //check if it's the right user using info.user.name or info.user.id
    bot.reply(message, info.user.name)
  })
})
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This answers how to get the user name using Botkit

Comment: I upvoted. Looks like the right answer, especially given the original poster is using BotKit syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**[users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list)** This method returns a list of all users in the team. This includes deleted/deactivated users. This method has the URL https://slack.com/api/users.list

More information regarding [**Bot Users**](https://api.slack.com/bot-users)

Comment: And if you want info about a specific user ID, you can use https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info.

Answer (score 0):

This below helped me to get the username of a given userid, you can get the userid with message.user from main calling method

```
 getUserName(userID).then((output) => { username = output.user.name });


function getUserName(userid){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //get token from https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info
        options.uri = "https://slack.com/api/users.info?token=********&userid=" +userid+ "&pretty=";
         rp(options).then(function (body) {
            resolve(body);
            console.log('Retrieved Info slack --- ' + JSON.stringify(body));
       })
       .catch(function (err) {
             resolve(err);
             console.log('aborted - slack ' + JSON.stringify(err));
       });
   });
}
```

reference link : https://github.com/hassifow/Slack.API-User.info/blob/master/LambdaFunction.js